# How are google sheets api quotes counted?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets-api

I have a python code that every minute reads google sheets through api. After some time I face resource exhausted error.
First question would be how to catch this exception?
And second, most important, how are these qoutes counted? I.e. I have one call to function that starts communicqtion with sheets and than reads 20 rows. So is it one quote, or 20 of them?

```
try:
        scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/pi/Downloads/MeteoStation.json', scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    except:
        logging.error("Sheets settings opening error")
        return None
    else:
        sheet = client.open('Sheetname').worksheet("Settings")
        send_regular_sms=str(sheet.cell(4,5).value)
        send_pressure_sms=str(sheet.cell(6,5).value)
        measuring_diff=float(sheet.cell(8,5).value)
        pressure_diff=float(sheet.cell(10,5).value)
        sms_delay=float(sheet.cell(12,5).value)
        sms_pressure_stop=float(sheet.cell(14,5).value)
        return [client,send_regular_sms,send_pressure_sms]
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your current script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I've added it in question. It's shorten in order its not to long but you can get the sensation what is idea behind

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the script. In your script, it seems that one API is used to retrieve a value. So for example, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve all values by one API. 2. Parse each value from the retrieved values. By this, the number of use of the API can be reduced. If this was not the direction you want, I have to apologize.

Comment: so you are suggesting using `spreadsheets.values.get()` and then consolidating these values prior to return?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your situation, gspread can be used. So for example, how about using the method of `get_all_values()`? [Ref](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0):

For handling the errors you can use ***googleapiclient module***

To install it use:

```
pip install google-api-python-client
```

then use  try/except in this way:

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
try:
   ...
except HttpError as err:
    print(err)
```

About the other part of your question, use the method `.row_values()` which you can see in the docs [here](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/gspread/latest/gspread.pdf) on page 13, so you can get all the rows and save some calls, but anyways keep in mind the limits shown [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) in the Google Sheets API docs